# Generating a random displacement on the unit sphere

Tags: c, random, gsl

Given a unit vector **n**, I need to generate, *as fast as possible*, another random unit vector **m**. The deviation of **m** from **n** should be on the order of a positive parameter `sigma`, and the distribution of **m** on the unit sphere should be symmetrical around **n**.

I have no specific requirements on the representation of unit vectors, so you can use spherical angles, Cartesian coordinates, or whatever turns out to be convenient. Also, there are no precise requirements on the probability distributions used, as long as it decays when **m** deviates more than `sigma` from **n**.

I am working with `gsl` and `C`. I have come up with a somewhat convoluted method using Cartesian coordinates. I will post it later if it is useful, but I would like to see people's ideas.

Comment: To clarify: does `The deviation of m from n should be on the order of a positive parameter sigma` mean `The angle between m and n should be normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation sigma`?

Comment: @japreiss Something like that. But since I don't want place any restrictions on the coordinates used, perhaps someone finds it more convenient to use the distance between **m** and **n** instead of the angle. That's why I wasn't precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably know that vectors with each dimension  **uniformly** distributed about `0` result in a cube of points with more values concentrated in the corners.  But vectors with each dimension **normally** distributed about `0` are much nicer.  The points' polar angles are uniformly distributed on the unit sphere, and their radii are concentrated near the origin. You can generate vectors like this, changing the standard deviation based on your parameter `sigma`.  Add the vectors to `n`, normalize the result, and call it good.

This requires one square root and 3 normally distributed random numbers.  You can get normally distributed random numbers quickly using the [Ziggurat algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm).  A more approximate option is summing 3 or more uniformly distributed random numbers.  Yet another possibility: precompute a table of many random vectors and do a table lookup with a random index.  Each of these methods balances computation and storage differently, so you should code them all and test for speed.

Comment: +1 Thanks! This is much nicer than what I was doing. I'll program it and see how it goes. If nothing else shows up I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use spherical polar coordinates. Generate an azimuthal angle from a uniform distribution over the interval [0,2*pi) and a polar angle according to some kind of exponential decay distribution chosen such that your decay requirements are met. You can then just generate the **m** vector as the angular displacement of the original **n** vector by these randomly sampled polar and azimuthal angles.

Comment: As I said, I am using Cartesian coordinates, and what I am doing is almost the same as what you suggest. The problem is that I need to run this random generator millions of times. In Cartesian coordinates the trig function calls are kept to a minimum. I didn't know how to reduce the number of trig function calls using other coordinates.